# Annotate Boolean field if item is in a python list

Tags: django, django-orm

I have an app for a Restaurant. And I have this model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

I have a list called TopSelled like this:

```
['Beer', 'Burger', ...]
```

I want to aggregate a boolean field called 'Hot', depending if  product item is "top-sell" or not.

So my annotation should be something like this:

```
Product.objects.all().annotate(if Product.Name in List: HOT = True ELSE Hot = False)
```

How can I achieve this? Thx!

Comment: Won't it be better to just add a boolean field hot into your Product model? And then when you do `Product.objects.all()`, you can loop through the QuerySet and just change Product.hot = True.

Comment: I already did what you suggested. But performance is not very good. I am trying to do this with Aggregate(avoid a For Loop) and compare performance. Thanks!

Comment: Oh great, thanks for your input! I didn't think about performance as much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try annotating with `Case`:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField
from django.db.models.expressions import Case, When

Product.objects.annotate(hot=Case(
        When(name__in=hot_list, then=True), 
        output_field=BooleanField())
    ).filter(hot=True)
```